# Why don't terms cancel in this application of Bayes' Rule?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

I have been looking at several different sites trying to wrap my head around the content of Sebastian Thrun's Intro AI course on Udacity. At the moment I'm trying to understand the lesson on "explaining away" in the case of two confounding causes. I found [this SE Mathematics article](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1281454) but the top answer just left me with more questions.

Let 
S = It is sunny
R = I got a raise
H = I am happy

The first step in the article linked above is to go from

P(R|H,S)

to

P(R,H,S) / P(H,S)

I understand how to make that step. What I don't understand is why the denominator doesn't cancel out the P(S) and the P(H) in the numerator. I thought that P(R,H,S) was the same as P(R)P(H)P(S), so dividing that by P(H)P(S) would leave you with P(R).

I've always struggled with math, so I'm sure I'm just missing something dumb.

Comment: Think about what these cryptic expressions mean. The event $R$ (“I got a raise”) includes cases when it’s sunny or you aren’t happy, but we want to exclude those for the conditional probability, so $P(R)$ can’t in general be the right value.

Comment: If $S,H,R$ were independent you might be correct as $\dfrac{ P(R)P(H)P(S)}{P(H)P(S)} = P(R)$ as you say, but they need not be independent, especially as the weather and your pay may influence your happiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE:

$P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}\ne P(A)P(B)$

so in your case :

$P(R|H,S) = \dfrac{P(R,H,S)}{P(H,S)}$

This is known as [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)

EDIT 1:

on the question that $P(A,B) =P(A)P(B)$.

The above is only true iff $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are independent events.

It would be best to read up on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory))

EDIT 2:

To answer your question :

> Does that imply that it is not possible to calculate P(A, B) unless you know P(A|B) or P(B|A) (assuming that A and B are independent?)

No, you can also use the fact that $P(A\cap B) =P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$

Comment: I apologize in advance for being so dense, but in the top transformation, doesn't P(A,B) expand to P(A)P(B), in which case the P(B) in the denominator would cancel out the P(B) in the numerator? It's the same question, just with two variables instead of three.

Comment: @DanielArant: No, $P(A,B)$ is in general not equal to $P(A)P(B)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory).

Comment: @DanielArant not always $P(A,B)= P(A)P(B) $ iff $P(A) \& P(B)$ are independent events

Comment: Does that imply that it is not possible to calculate P(A, B) unless you know P(A|B) or P(B|A) (assuming that A and B are independent?)

Comment: @DanielArant no you can also use the fact that $P(A\cup B)= P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

Comment: Could you summarize these points in your answer? Then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @DanielArant okay