# Calculating probabilities when events are neither independent nor mutually exclusive

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider three events: $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_3$. They are neither mutually exclusive nor independent. Let's say that the correlation coefficient between $E_i$ and $E_j$ is given by $\rho_{ij}$. Let's also assume that the probability of $E_i$ occurring is $P(E_i)$.

How do we calculate the probability that at least one of these three events occurs? Any references that develop a general methodology to calculate probabilities when events share these two characteristics (mutually non-exclusive and correlated)?

Any help much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not enough information to find this probability.

Comment: Perhaps $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_3$ take values in $\{0,1\}$, and the probability of $E_i$ occurring is $P(E_i=1)$. That seems to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of at least one event occurring is found by the principle of inclusion and exclusion:

$$\mathsf P(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3)=\sum_{i=1}^3\mathsf P(E_i)~-~\sum_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant 3}\mathsf P(E_i,E_j)~+~\mathsf P(E_1,E_2,E_3)$$

But... **You do not have enough information.**

---

If you know the marginal probabilities and correlation coefficients, then you can find the three pairwise joint probabilities: $\mathsf P(E_i,E_j)$.

$$\begin{align}
\rho_{ij}&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(E_i,E_j)-\mathrm P(E_i)\mathsf P(E_j)}{\sqrt{(\mathsf P(E_i)-\mathsf P(E_i)^2)(\mathsf P(E_j)-\mathsf P(E_j)^2)~}}
\\[3ex]
\therefore\qquad\mathsf P(E_i,E_j)&=\mathrm P(E_i)\mathsf P(E_j)+\rho_{ij}\sqrt{(\mathsf P(E_i)-\mathsf P(E_i)^2)(\mathsf P(E_j)-\mathsf P(E_j)^2)~}
\end{align}$$

---

Unfortunately, this will **not** provide the tripplewise joint probability: $\mathsf P(E_1,E_2,E_3)$ and this is needed too.

Comment: Thank you! I think knowing a few conditional probabilities between those events takes us a step closer, since we can then use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281454/bayes-rule-with-3-variables/1281558#1281558